# ASP.NET - return value from iframe to main page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, printing, dialog, return

I have an iframe on a usercontrol. I need to print webpage which I load on iframe dynamically.  I am able to reach this far.  But I am not able to makeout whether user has actually printed or not.
I have javascript function print() called in the webpage on iframe.
When print dialog is displayed, I need to know whether user selected OK(to print) or cancel and pass the same back to usercontrol.
Any ideas as to how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. The browser will not inform you if the printing has been done or cancelled.

You can use `onafterprint` event to some extent but that is only supported on FF and IE. On IE 10 for example, the event is fired before the print dialog is even opened.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing